# How to split 100 million (18.5 GB) csv rows into 50k each small excel files

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to split a large CSV file into 50k rows Excel files. I tried using pandas but unfortunately it is getting crashed. So I switched to polar. It is working but the problem is it is only creating single files of 100k rows. How can I generate 50k rows excel files from 100 million (18.5 GB) csv file?

First I have given `next_batches(50000)` but still it is giving me only one excel file. So I have tried to `print` the `len` and it gave me one as output

```
import os
import polars as pl

def split_csv_to_excel(csv_file_path, output_dir, batch_size=50000):
    reader = pl.read_csv_batched(csv_file_path,batch_size=batch_size)
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    
    batches = reader.next_batches(1)

    for i, df in enumerate(batches):
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"batch_{i}.xlsx")
        df.write_excel(output_file_path)


split_csv_to_excel("inputpath","outputpath")
```

Comment: Never forget that a csv is a text file! But if it can contain *complex fields*, notably fields containing newline characters, using the `csv` module is a sure way to process the file in streaming mode, meaning loading only  one single row in memory at a time...

Comment: I tried using CSV but it is giving me an error: _csv. Error: Field larger than field limit (131072)

Comment: If you have column values (text) greater than or equal to 32k in length, you won't be able to create a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet

Comment: @Codist The actual limit is 1,048,576 rows I don't how it got created I have exported the data using db beaver, but the problem is I am unable to open it as Excel is getting crashed. So I am trying to split it into multiple files. Please help me if you have any solution for this problem, I tried for 30k still it is giving me the same error error: _csv. Error: Field larger than field limit (131072) using csv module

Comment: @IndratejReddy  1,048,576 is the row limit. You say you have a field size > 131,072

Comment: @Codist No, but I have around 100 million rows which is around 18.5 gb

Comment: @IndratejReddy The number of rows in your CSV is not important because you can break that down into convenient chunks (e.g., 50,000 at a time) but if you have a **field size** of > 131,072 anywhere in that file, you will **not** be able to create a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet

Comment: @Codist No I don't see any field with that size

Comment: @IndratejReddy I quote your earlier comment "I tried using CSV but it is giving me an error: _csv. Error: Field larger than field limit (131072)"

Comment: @Codist is that is the case then how can polars able to create a excel file ?

Comment: Please show the `pandas` and/or `csv` code attempts that crashed or raised error. Pandas supports iterating on file using chunks. The field limit error likely is due to incorrect quoting or delimiters which other packages have defaults but not `csv`. A snippet of sample data helps for [mre].

Comment: This question is specifically asking about using Polars `read_csv_batched` method. It should not be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: "*I have exported the data using db beaver*" is there any chance you can keep this data in a database (you can easily set one up yourself using docker) instead of exporting to CSV's + reading it back in using Python? Both pandas as polars have neat database interfaces that allows you to retrieve query results. I imagine you want to do something with the data, and doing that with a bunch of Excel files each holding 50k rows will very likely be more uncomfortable than having a db you can query. Perhaps you can include *what* you want to do with this data in the end?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I respect your suggestions and I wish I can do that but the problem is it took 3 days to get the data in the table and if I ran a query it took more than that's why I have exported as CSV after 1 hour it somehow worked

Comment: Still interested in what your final goal is... If your query takes 3 days on a 18.5 GB database I would be curious what query you were doing and what indices you have. I'm not saying it's impossible that your approach is the optimal one, it's just that db-systems have all kinds of features to work with large datasets. If setting up a server is too cumbersome you could also look at something like [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/). Good luck!

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke it kind of getting 3 months' logs, our systems generate too much data every day, is there a way like a frist fetch  0 to 100000 records in one query and then go to fetch the next 100000 records like 100001 row to 2000001  and so on ..

Comment: I would suggest writing a new question on how to limit/offset queries to return a subset of results after doing some research, e.g.: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html Here is another resource where someone analyses their structured logs in sqlite and duckdb: https://tersesystems.com/blog/2023/03/04/ad-hoc-structured-log-analysis-with-sqlite-and-duckdb/

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the docs could be made clearer.

If you look at the [final `while` example](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv_batched.html) - you basically need to loop over `.next_batches` and keep calling it.

```py
count = 0
batches = reader.next_batches(5)

while batches:
    for df in batches:
        count += 1
        
        filename = f"batch_{count}.xlsx"
        print("[WRITE]:", filename)
        
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
        df.write_excel(output_file_path)
        
    batches = reader.next_batches(5)
```

As this while-pattern is quite common, [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) exists as a way to turn it into a for loop:

```py
count = 0
batches = iter(lambda: reader.next_batches(5), None)
    
for batch in batches:
    for df in batch:
        count += 1
        ...
```

#### Example run with 100m lines

```py
import polars as pl

from multiprocessing import get_context
from pathlib import Path

def create_sample_input(filename="input.csv", num_lines=100_000_000):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write("COLUMN0\n")
        f.write("\n".join(map(str, range(num_lines))))
    return filename

def split_csv():
    reader = pl.read_csv_batched(create_sample_input())

    count = 0
    batches = reader.next_batches(5)
    while batches:
        for df in batches:
            count += 1
            filename = f"batch_{count}.xlsx"
            output_file_path = output_dir / filename
            yield df, output_file_path
        batches = reader.next_batches(5)
 
def write_excel(args):
    df, filename = args
    df.write_excel(filename)

def read_excel(filename):
    return dict(filename=filename.name, height=pl.read_excel(filename).height)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_dir = Path(".")

    with get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
         pool.map(write_excel, (args for args in split_csv()))

         df = pl.DataFrame(
             pool.map(read_excel, output_dir.glob("batch_*.xlsx"))
         )
         print(df)
```

#### Output

```py
shape: (2_008, 2)
┌─────────────────┬────────┐
│ filename        ┆ height │
│ ---             ┆ ---    │
│ str             ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════════╪════════╡
│ batch_709.xlsx  ┆ 50001  │
│ batch_359.xlsx  ┆ 50001  │
│ batch_1380.xlsx ┆ 50001  │
│ batch_1695.xlsx ┆ 50001  │
│ …               ┆ …      │
│ batch_1194.xlsx ┆ 50001  │
│ batch_1481.xlsx ┆ 50001  │
│ batch_1878.xlsx ┆ 50001  │
│ batch_458.xlsx  ┆ 50001  │
└─────────────────┴────────┘
```

Not sure why the batch size varies

```py
>>> df['height'].value_counts()
shape: (9, 2)
┌────────┬────────┐
│ height ┆ counts │
│ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ u32    │
╞════════╪════════╡
│ 28572  ┆ 13     │
│ 50001  ┆ 1984   │
│ 43751  ┆ 5      │
│ 35186  ┆ 1      │
│ 13457  ┆ 1      │
│ 45658  ┆ 1      │
│ 33334  ┆ 1      │
│ 47121  ┆ 1      │
│ 33069  ┆ 1      │
└────────┴────────┘
```

But no input is lost.

```py
>>> df["height"].sum()
100000000
```

Comment: Hi jqurious, I have tried your solution using while loop but still it is generating only one csv file of 1048576

Comment: @IndratejReddy I can't replicate that behaviour - it works for me as expected. Are you changing `batch_size` and/or `.next_batches(N)`?

Comment: please try with a data set of at least 20 gb and see how it works

Comment: @IndratejReddy That's not really feasible right now. I increased it to 10million lines and it still splits into multiple files.

Comment: Okay well I increased to 100million and added multiprocessing to speed up reading/writing. Slight batch size variations are still present, but no input is lost.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using pandas exclusively**

Notice that `chunks` below is an iterator (so that the *entire* `CSV` does not go to memory, while converting the chunk to an Excel file).

```
def split_csv_pandas(csv_file, output_prefix, rows_file=50000):
    chunks = pd.read_csv(csv_file, chunksize=rows_file)
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        excel_file = f"{output_prefix}_{i+1}.xlsx"
        chunk.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)

path_input =  'effects-of-covid-19-on-trade-at-15-december-2021-provisional.csv'
path_output = 'output_file'
split_csv_pandas(path_input, path_output)
```

---

**Solution using duckdb + pandas**

Another possible solution consists in using `duckdb`, which can handle large `CSV` files (even when they do not fit memory). I am using the `CSV` file at [file](https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Effects-of-COVID-19-on-trade/Effects-of-COVID-19-on-trade-At-15-December-2021-provisional/Download-data/effects-of-covid-19-on-trade-at-15-december-2021-provisional.csv) as an example.

The `CSV` file is read by chunks of 50000 rows. In case we have enough memory, there is no need to read the `CSV` file by chunks!

```
import duckdb
import pandas as pd

def split_csv(csv_file, output_prefix, rows_file=50000):
    conn = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:')

    result = conn.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM read_csv_auto('{csv_file}')").fetchall()
    nrows = result[0][0]
    
    # number of files needed
    nfiles = -(-nrows // rows_file)
    
    for file_idx in range(nfiles):
        offset = file_idx * rows_file
        query = f"SELECT * FROM read_csv_auto('{csv_file}') LIMIT {rows_file} OFFSET {offset}"
        df = conn.execute(query).fetchdf()

        if not df.empty:
            excel_file = f"{output_prefix}_{file_idx+1}.xlsx"
            df.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)

    conn.close()

path_input = 'effects-of-covid-19-on-trade-at-15-december-2021-provisional.csv'
path_output = 'output_file'
split_csv(path_input, path_output)
```

Comment: What's with `nfiles = -(-nrows // rows_file)` please?

Comment: That is to calculate the number of excel files that are needed, @MarkSetchell. The `-` signs are to deal with cases as `total_rows // rows_per_file` would result in `2` for `100,050 // 50,000`, ignoring the last 50 rows. However, `-(-total_rows // rows_per_file)` would result in `3`, correctly indicating that a third file is needed for the remaining rows.

Comment: @PaulS I tried your solution but unfortunately When I compare the size of splitted folder and the large csv file on windows, I see a huge difference,  splitted folder  contains 215 files contains 2.5 gb so I can see huge data loss I am not seeing 17gb or 18gb size

Comment: which of my two solutions you are referring to, @IndratejReddy?

Comment: `10000000 // 50000 = 200`. So, I guess there is no rows missing. I suspect that some columns may be missing (maybe, because of the column separator), @IndratejReddy.

Comment: @PaulS I appreciate your help unfortunately I can't share the data file, we can try with dummy csv file at least of 20 GB and go the folder where you splited the files and click on properties of that folder you will see data is missing it will come to 2gb or something

Comment: I suspect that your `CSV` file may be malformed, as the same issue appears to occur with a different approach, as with @DeanMacGregor's code.

Answer (score 0):

This has an explicit check on the batch size before it writes an excel file to force it to 50k despite whatever buffer/batch processing that is happening in the background which prevents those settings to match row counts exactly.

```
import polars as pl

row_size=50_000
reader = pl.read_csv_batched(Your_File)
batch = pl.concat(reader.next_batches(1))
n = max([batch.shape[0]//row_size,1])
outname_prefix="xlfile"
xl_file_count=0
while True: # outer loop for unknown total row count
    # Check batch size against target row size
    if batch.shape[0]>=row_size:
        # if bigger then write first 50k to file and keep leftover
        write_size, batch = batch[0:row_size], batch[row_size:]
        write_size.write_excel(f"{outname_prefix}{xl_file_count}.xlsx")
        xl_file_count+=1
    else:
        # if smaller than target then get next batch
        next_batch = reader.next_batches(n)
        if next_batch is None:
            # if there is no next batch, that's end of file
            if batch.shape[0]>0:
                # still need to write last remainder
                batch.write_excel(f"{outname_prefix}{xl_file_count}.xlsx")
            break
        # if there is a next_batch then combine with existing batch
        next_batch = pl.concat(next_batch)
        batch=pl.concat([batch,next_batch])
```

Comment: After seeing your code, what I have understood is batching  pl.read_csv_batched(Your_File) is unpredictable we can't fix how many rows should be taken for each batch and may I know why in line 6 batch = pl.concat(reader.next_batches(1)) you concating, we can directly take batch = reader.next_batches(1) right?

Comment: `next_batches` returns a list of batches. With `next_batches(1)` you could just take the 0th element of that list but if you ever changed the 1 to something bigger then taking just the 0th element would lose data.

Comment: I ran it but unfortunately for me, it is giving only 750 MB out of 17.2 GB while I open and check properties of folder that contains all the spitted excel files

Comment: @IndratejReddy It seems from this, and other comments, that you have a malformed csv or one with properties that need to be specified to the reader (maybe non standard escape characters) which is causing it to finish early